# Error trying to connect Power BI Desktop with MariaDB running on Docker CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, docker, powerbi, mariadb, odbc

I was trying to make the connection but Power BI shows this error:

"The 'Driver' property with value '{MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver}' doesn't correspond to an installed ODBC driver."

I've been following this site to configure the ODBC Driver :

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/

this one for the data source:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/creating-a-data-source-with-mariadb-connectorodbc/

and this one to make the connection:

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/getting-started-with-the-mariadb-direct-query-adapter-for-microsoft-power-bi/

I followed all the steps, even when i try :

```
$ isql MariaDB-server
```

The connection is succesfull

These are my:

odbc.ini

```
[MariaDB-server]
Description=MariaDB server
Driver=MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/tmp/trace.log
SERVER=xxx.x.x.x
USER=root
PASSWORD=xx
DATABASE=powerbiTest
PORT=3306
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=3

odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**What ive tried**

1- Re-installing Power Bi

2- Creating another Docker Container

3- Installing ODBC Driver from source

4- Using MariaDB driver as Default modifying the .ini files

5- Changing parameters like servername, password ,etc

Id be grateful if anyone could help me!
Thanks!